# Redirecting pipe from file to screen linux c

Tags: c, linux, file, pipe

I have the following code (found it on internet)

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("text.txt","w");
int fd=open("text.txt",O_WRONLY,S_IWUSR);
dup2(fd,1);
```

This code redirect the pipe from screen to a file named `text.txt`.
Now i need to do the opposite. I want to change the pipe writing from this file to the screen.
Does anyone have an idea? Thank you

Comment: there is no 'pipe' anywhere in the posted code.   However, there is some changing of the `stdout` I/O stream from the terminal to a file.

Comment: piping is when you use a pipe (a special "fifo" kind of file which can have no name) between two pieces of code. Here, what you do is redirecting.

Comment: yeah you're right maybe i didn't explain like it should be, my problem is that i want to redirect the output back to stdout "screen"

Answer (score 1):

That code only works because something is pushing data into the pipe.  That would not be the case if you simply reversed the wiring of guzintas and comzoutas.  You'll need to open the text file for reading and then read the file into memory and write it to the screen.  There's lots of examples of source code out there for clones of cat.exe, go look on GitHub for the code.

Here's a very simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void spewfile(FILE *fp)
{
  char buf[BUFSIZ];

  while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp))
    fputs(buf, stdout);
}
```

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files that are not used.  In this case, suggest removing the two statements: `#include <string.h>` and `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: I will probably be simpler to do `cat "text.txt"`

Comment: @Camion agreed, but I think the OP was under the impression that they could somehow reverse the redirections in their console to file example and get file to console instead, which simply won't work if the file isn't a pipe with something pushing data into it.  I merely tried to show an example of how to successfully push the bits from the file to the console.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can write to `/dev/tty`, but this is not equivalent to restoring writing to stdout, since you probably won't be able to redirect output from the calling program (Not sure - to be tested), and by the way, I'm not sure this is portable to other Unix based systems.

```
int fd=open("/dev/tty",O_WRONLY);
dup2(fd,1);
```

Otherwise, you should dup your file descriptor 1 to another one before the first redirection, so that you would be able to restore it later.

```
/* save fd 1 */
int sav=dup(1);

/* redirect to file */
int fd=open("text.txt",O_WRONLY,S_IWUSR);
dup2(fd,1);

/* done anything you wanted here (redirected to text.txt) */
/* ... */

/* revert redirection */
dup2(sav,1);

/* do anything you want here (having reverted the redirection back to stdout) */
/* ... */
```

By the way, one should probably avoid using both buffered (fopen) and unbuffered (open) I/O at the same time. This will cause problems since the buffered I/O are not informed of what you do at the same time with the unbuffered I/O.

Comment: What exactly causes text.txt output to be pushed to stdout in this scenario?

Comment: If your program has it's output externally directed to text.txt (i.e. my_program > text.txt), the first scenario will force it's output to screen)

Comment: No, the OP's original code directs console input to text.txt and they want to reverse that flow.  How does your program read data from text.txt and display it on stdout?

Comment: This is your interpretation, but it is not clearly stated like that in the question. He never told he wanted to read output sent to the file, he told he wanted to reverse a redirection of an output previously sent to a file. IMO, there are two different scenario : Either the initial redirection was made outside the program, or it was made inside.

Comment: I think your code writes to text.txt, which is exactly what the OP already knows how to do.  They clearly state they want to display the text file content on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, ok. I changed the comments to make thing clearer